# Vendor-agnostic free software to provision cloud instances and run scripts on them

Tags: open-source, bash, cloud-computing

I am looking for generic software which performs the following:

1. Spins up a server on a cloud (vendor agnostic) or local VM (ideally)
2. Transfers a bash script to the new server
3. Runs the bash script, waiting as long as is necessary before
4. Performs post-script actions such as downloading a file

It could look like this:

```
./runOnCloud.sh
    --credentials=filecontainingcloudcredentials.json
    --cloud=amazon
    --type=x3.3large
    --preemptible=true
    --download=/tmp/filetodownloadfromremotemachine.tar.gz
    scriptToRunOnRemoteMachine.sh
```

`runOnCloud.sh` doesn't have to be a Bash script of course, it could be Java or a binary or anything, as long as it automates and takes the trouble out of provisioning the machine, I don't really mind.

Comment: Have you tried vagrant? https://www.vagrantup.com/

Comment: No, that seems very close to what I need. A few years ago I read about Vagrant, never used it, and then forgot about it, so thanks for the reminder! Feel free to add a proper answer (especially the bit about retrieving a generated file from the VM) and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Vagrant

[Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) seems like the perfect choice for your needs.

### Multi-cloud

Vagrant supports numerous cloud providers and local virtualization technologies.  Built-in support exists for "VirtualBox, Hyper-V, and Docker".  There is a plugin architecture which has allowed a diverse set of folks to build support for cloud providers.  Plugins and tutorials for [AWS](https://blog.scottlowe.org/2016/09/15/using-vagrant-with-aws/) with Vagrant, or [Google Cloud](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-google) are easy to find.

### Shell scripts

Vagrant has a [Shell Provisioner](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/shell.html) that seems to cover what you're looking for.

> Combined with a little bit more Ruby, this makes it very easy to embed your shell scripts directly within your Vagrantfile. Another example below:
>
> ```
> $script = <<-SCRIPT
> echo I am provisioning...
> date > /etc/vagrant_provisioned_at
> SCRIPT
>
> Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
>   config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $script
> end
> ```

### Downloading a file

Vagrant supports `ssh`/`scp` so it is easy to download or upload files anytime.